# Why do my inserted image in html not show in gmail when using smtplib

Tags: python, html, gmail, smtplib

I have written a python code to send emails with python by my outlook application to multiple recievers. I noticed that all recipients that have a gmail account are not able to see ny images that I have inserted into my html code (note that outlook recipients do see the images). I have googled around and tried different approaches but not yet solved the issue..

Below is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
s.starttls()
s.login('xxxx@hotmail.com', "xxxx")
me = 'xxxx PRENUMERATION <xxxxx@hotmail.com>'


# creating message object
msg = MIMEMultipart()

# Setting the parameters for the message
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = "xxxx@gmail.com"
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing'

html = """

                                <tr>
                                    <td class="x_template-container-cell" align="center" style="padding: 0;">
                                        <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: auto; background-color: #ffffff;">
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="x_menu-box-start" align="left" valign="center" style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-top: 15px;">
                                                    <a
                                                            href="https://xxxx.nu/"
                                                            target="_blank"
                                                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                                            data-auth="NotApplicable"
                                                            style="text-decoration: none; color: #000001;"
                                                            data-linkindex="1"
                                                    >
                                                        <img
                                                                data-imagetype="External"
                                                                src="cid:foodlogfive"
                                                                width="50"
                                                                height="50"
                                                                border="0"
                                                                alt="HeaderLogo"
                                                                style="display: block; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none;"
                                                        />
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
"""


# Compose the message body
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))

fp = open('foodlogfive.png', 'rb')
foodlogfive = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

foodlogfive.add_header('Content-ID', 'foodlogfive')
foodlogfive.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename('foodlogfive.png'))
foodlogfive.add_header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")
msg.attach(foodlogfive)


# Send message using SMTP server
s.send_message(msg)
```